# how do I fix an ACPI error?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 22.04, acpi

I've recently upgraded to Kubuntu 22.04 LTS Jammy successfully.  The install appears to be running without issue.  Although, I have been seeing the following message upon boot / reboot ...

[image]

I've reinstalled the OS once without any change.  Can this be fixed?  Does it need to be fixed?  I am unsure what my options are at this point.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

--

[image]

Comment: If all works OK, then there is nothing to fix.

Comment: seeing errors on boot is normal, they aren't actually a problem, as long as your system is running normally